# Replace entire column dimension of ndarray by another array of same length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 5d ndarray in python that is defined like this

```
RGBXY = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7,8,9,10],
     #...100 more times
    [101,102,103,104,105],
]
```

and i have a nother array defined as

```
x = [0,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9...] #length same as RGBXY subarrays
```

And i would like to replace the 4th column by the values inside x
So if i wanted to replace themm by a single number i would just do

```
RGBXY[:,3:4] = 5
```

How can i replace the 4th column by the array in x?

Comment: Do you mean: `RGBXY[:, 3] = x`?  This will replace the fourth column (index 3) with the array defined as `x`.

Comment: That's a 2D array with 5 columns, not a 5D array

Answer (score 0):

If these are numpy arrays (or you're ok with using numpy) you should be able to assign it directly as follows, assuming all the lists in RGBXY are the same length:

```py
RGBXY = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [6,7,8,9,10],
    [101,102,103,104,105],
], dtype=float)

x = [0,0.3,0.4]

RGBXY[:, 3] = x
```

The value of RGBXY is then:

```
array([[  1. ,   2. ,   3. ,   0. ,   5. ],
       [  6. ,   7. ,   8. ,   0.3,  10. ],
       [101. , 102. , 103. ,   0.4, 105. ]])
```

Note I had to assign the data type of the array to float above, as all the original values are integers but your new x values are floats. Without that it was converting all the x values to int (all to zero in this case).

Answer (score -1):

There is a great way of doing this with np, that i wasnt aware of. Provided that the arrays are of the same length.

```
RGBXY[:,3] = x
```

To do it with itaration you can do

```
for i in range(len(RGBXY)): # For 0 - length of RGBXY array(number of elements in RGBXY)
    RGBXY[i][3] = x[i] # Assign the 4th(for loops counts from 0) column in the array to x at the same index.
```

Comment: Im getting: IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

Comment: You said the arrays where of the same length? right?

Comment: yes they should be. But this error indicates they are different lengths right?

Comment: Well, i would think so. This should iterate over every element in RGBXY, and set the 4th element in RGBXY[i] to x[i] or the nth element in x

Comment: Friendly note: Iteration is not required for this process, and strictly speaking is ‘discouraged’ (if you will) due to its inefficiency.  Broadcasting, is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! @S3DEV Looked into it, and fixed my answer.